# accessing value of object when the object key is the same as current user id (angular & firebase)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an object on firebase where each of the keys are user ids:

[image]

I know want to display the "500" on the front end. I have a service that generates `currentUserId` which is equal to the object key of this object. I then try to display this like so:

```
{{(bedroom$ | async)?.mid_tenants._auth.currentUserId}}
```

where as mention `_auth.currentUserId` is the same id as this key. However when I do this i get this error returned:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUserId' of undefined
```

however if I do `console.log(this._auth.currentUserId)` in the constructor, it returns the correct id..

Comment: How in your code do you get `this._auth.currentUserId`?

Comment: @camden_kid :  get currentUserId(): string {
    return this.authenticated ? this.currentUser.uid : null;
  }